# Mongo service doesn't connect

Tags: mongodb, database

I just did a manual installation of mongoDB like the documentation says and when I run `./mongo`command this is what I get.

```
./mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
```

It doesn't say anymore and doesn't connect to `test`database.
Anyone know how can I solve this problem?

Thank's in advance

EDIT: I uninstall all and re-install using Brew. Now this is what I get when I run `mongod`

```
all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
```

And this when i run `mongo`

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: test
Wed Jan  8 13:35:04.634 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:145
exception: connect failed
```

And this is what `/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`shows

```
***** SERVER RESTARTED *****


Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=745 port=27017 dbpath=/usr/local/var/mongodb 64-bit host=MacBook-Pro-de-Kemical.local
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] 
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.8
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] build info: Darwin minimountain.local 12.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.749 [initandlisten] options: { bind_ip: "127.0.0.1", config: "/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf", dbpath: "/usr/local/var/mongodb", logappend: "true", logpath: "/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log" }
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10310 Unable to lock file: /usr/local/var/mongodb/mongod.lock. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 dbexit: 
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Wed Jan  8 13:34:11.750 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you actually started the "mongod" server process?

If you have, you need to find out what is happening and one way to do this is with the "strace" tool. Running it like follows creates a log file in /tmp/strace.log and that should tell you system level wise what's going on:

```
strace -o /tmp/strace.log ./mongo
```